# How to run concurrent job with dependent tasks?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have a situation that I need to work on

I have a class which has send method, example

```
@Singleton
class SendReport {

 public void send() {}
}
```

The send method is called from a user click on web page, and must return immediately, but must start a sequence of tasks that will take time

```
send
 ->|
   | |-> Task1
 <-|      |
        <-|
          | 
        |-> Task2 (can only start when Task1 completes/throws exception)
        <-|
          | 
        |-> Task3 (can only start when Task2 completes/throws exception)
        <-|
```

I am new to Java concurrent world and was reading about it. As per my understanding, I need a `Executor Service` and `submit()` a job(`Task1`) to process and get the `Future` back to continue.

Am I correct?

The difficult part for me to understand and design is
- How and where to handle exceptions by any such task?
- As far as I see, do I have to do something like?

```
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    Future futureTask1 = executorService.submit(new Callable(){
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("doing Task1");
        return "Task1 Result";
    }
    });
    if (futureTask1.get() != null) {
    Future futureTask2 = executorService.submit(new Callable(){
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("doing Task2");
        return "Task2 Result";
    }
    }
    ... and so on for Task 3
```

Is it correct?
if yes, is there a better recommended way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have a line of tasks that need to be called on completion of the previous one than as stated and discussed in the previous answers I don't think you need multiple threads at all.

If you have a pool of tasks and some of them needs to know the outcome of another task while others don't care you can then come up with a dependent callable implementation.

```
public class DependentCallable implements Callable {

private final String name;
private final Future pre;

public DependentCallable(String name, Future pre) {
    this.name = name;
    this.pre = pre;
}

@Override
public Object call() throws Exception {
    if (pre != null) {
        pre.get();
        //pre.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    System.out.println(name);
    return name;
}
```

A few other things you need to take care of based on the code in your question, get rid of future.gets in between submits as stated in previous replies. Use a thread pool size of which is at least greater than the depth of dependencies between callables.

Answer (score 1):

[Dependent task execution](https://reachmnadeem.wordpress.com/2016/09/01/introducing-dexecutor/) is made easy with Dexecutor

Disclaimer : I am the owner

Here is an example, it can run the following complex graph very easily, you can refer [this](https://github.com/dexecutor/dexecutor-core/wiki/How-Do-I-%3F) for more details

[image]

Here is [an example](https://github.com/dexecutor/dexecutor-examples#1-migration-application)

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach will not work as it will block till the total completion which you wanted to avoid.

future.get() is blocking();
so after submitting first Task, your code will wait till its finished and then next task will be submitted, again wait, so there is no advantage over single thread executing the tasks one by one.

so if anything the code would need to be:

```
Future futureTask2 = executorService.submit(new Callable(){
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        futureTask1.get()
        System.out.println("doing Task2");
        return "Task2 Result";
    }
}
```

your graph suggests that the subsequent task should execute despite exceptions. The ExecutionException will be thrown from get if there was problem with computation so you need to guard the get() with appropriate try.

Since Task1, Task2 have to completed one after another, why you do you want them exececuted in different threads. Why not have one thread with run method that deals with Task1,Task2.. one by one. As you said not your "main" thread, it can be in the executor job but one that handles all the tasks.

I personally don't like anonymous inner classes and callback (that is what you kind of mimic with chain of futures). If I would have to implement sequence of tasks I would actually implement queue of tasks and processors that executes them.

Mainly cause it is "more manageable", as I could monitor the content of the queue or even remove not necessary tasks.

So I would have a `BlockingQueue<JobDescription>` into which I would submit the JobDescription containing all the data necessary for the Task execution.

I would implement threads (Processors) that in their run() will have infinitive loop in which they take the job from the queue, do the task, and put back into the queue the following task. Something in those lines.

But if the Tasks are predefined at the send method, I would simply have them submitted as one job and then execute in one thread. If they are always sequential then there is no point in splitting them between different threads.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more task if you want to return send request immediately. Please check the following example. It submits the request to the background thread which will execute the tasks sequentially and then returns.

Callable Objects for 3 long running tasks.

```
public class Task1 implements Callable<String> {

    public String call() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Executing Task1...");
        return Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }
}

public class Task2 implements Callable<String> {

    public String call() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Executing Task2...");
        return Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }
}

public class Task3 implements Callable<String> {

    public String call() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Executing Task3...");
        return Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }
}
```

Main method that gets request from the client and returns immediately, and then starts executing tasks sequentially.

```
public class ThreadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Future<String> result1 = executorService.submit(new Task1());
                    if (result1.get() != null) {
                        Future<String> result2 = executorService.submit(new Task2());
                        if (result2.get() != null) {
                            executorService.submit(new Task3());
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Submitted request...");
    }

}
```